# Bluetooth choking

Tags: 15.04, bluetooth, strace

I had turned bluetooth off in the system settings, but `top` still showed it using 100% of CPU and `strace` shows a ton of lines like:

`poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}, {fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}, {fd=12, events=POLLIN}, {fd=13, events=POLLIN}, {fd=14, events=POLLIN}, {fd=15, events=POLLIN}, {fd=16, events=POLLIN}, {fd=17, events= POLLIN}, {fd=18, events=POLLIN}, {fd=19, events=POLLIN}, {fd=20, events=POLLIN}, {fd=21, events=POLLIN}, {fd=22, events=POLLIN}, {fd=24, events=POLLOUT}  ], 19, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=24, revents=POLLNVAL}])`

I accumulated something like 20,000,000 such lines in ten minutes.

What might be going on here?

Not sure if this is connected or Bluetooth is just unreliable and I should give up on it. https://askubuntu.com/questions/681844/how-do-i-troubleshoot-bluetooth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, my conclusion is that Bluetooth is unreliable and I give up.